# How to check if there is a number in prompt because all things are string in prompt?

Tags: javascript, string, prompt

`let b=prompt("");`

If in prompt someone enter 4 this will also come as a string, so how will I find that it is a number and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this:

```js
function isNumber(number) { 
  return Number.isInteger(number) || !isNaN(parseFloat(number)) && isFinite(number) 
}

var result = prompt("Enter your number");

if (!isNumber(result)) {
  console.log("This is not a number, Try Entering another.");
}
else {
  console.log("This is a number.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `isNaN` to check whether the input is a number or not

```js
// let a = prompt()
let a = "a"
const isNumber = (num) => !isNaN(parseInt(a))

console.log(isNumber(a))
a = "2";
console.log(isNumber(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

First Approach: Use `!isNaN()`

`isNaN(x)` returns true if `x` is not a number so invert it using `!` to get true whenever `x` is a number.

Second Approach: use typecasting

`Number(x)` will convert str to number and return the number and if `x` is not a number it will return NaN

```
b = prompt("")
return !isNaN(b)
```

This will return true if it is a number